# Drag : The smallest element emulates the Draggin's largest movement . both movements synchronized as if I was dragging both simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, drag

I have 2 images inside a container each. They are diferents sizes And I need to be able to dragg the largest one and the smaller just emulates the moves in it's scale.

For Example I have a 100x100px container with the largest img inside and the second 50x50px container with the same image inside.
Both images are  scaled to his containers by css width :50%.

```
<div>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvqLi5J2r36je08FneCZ-BScJu1ho5zFAEslVBY7D7cK38RmJxRA" class=' editing' />
</div>
<div id='c'>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvqLi5J2r36je08FneCZ-BScJu1ho5zFAEslVBY7D7cK38RmJxRA" class=' editing' />
</div>
```

I readapted and script to simulate the dragging to the second image, but
I don't know why the second image is not responding to the half of the coordinates. ( There's a log where you can see that) in the following example :

http://jsfiddle.net/blackersoul/nRhHb/

**So,in short, all I need is to get exactlly the same movement in the 2nd container, both movements synchronized as if I was dragging both simultaneously.**